# a new object throw "Unexpected token." nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, es6-class

I try to create a new object from a class
and it returns error "Unexpected token ."

**but when I create it as a singleton class and export the object it's work**

```
import {GoogleSheet} from "../modules/googleSheet";

class List {
  constructor(){
    this._googleSheet =  new GoogleSheet('siteList');
  }
}

var GoogleClient = require('./googleClient');
export class GoogleSheet extends GoogleClient{

    constructor(sheet){
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's going on with your class `Listes`? `new` is an invalid token in that case.

Comment: Please stop constantly changing the code. Post the one version that produces the error you described (a [mcve]), and we'll be able to help you with that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue come from this block :

```
class Listes {
 new GoogleSheet('siteList')
}
```

If you want a Listes object to contain a GoogleSheet object when instanciated, you will need to do something like :

```
class Listes {
   constructor() {
      this.googleSheet = new GoogleSheet('siteList');
   }
}
```